# How to use $.ajax on node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cmd

I want to use ajax on nodejs. Something like that:

`$.ajax('/postmessage'{method: "POST",data:{message: 'foo', username: 'bar'})`

Comment: You don't typically use jQuery with Node.js so you would not use `$.ajax()`. You would normally make web requests with something like the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. There is one caveat. The following:

```
$.ajax('/postmessage'{method: "POST",data:{message: 'foo', username: 'bar'})
```

Sends this HTTP request:

```
POST /postMessage HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

message=foo&username=bar
```

Your use of axios would send the following:

```
POST /postMessage HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"message":"foo", "username":"bar"}
```

This is indicated in the [axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) and is a deliberate choice as one of the main use cases for axios is the consumption REST APIs.

node.js has a built-in `querystring` module, allowing you to feed a string as body content of the POST request to axios, as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios'); 
const querystring = require("querystring");
const instance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'sitehere' });

instance.post('/postmessage', querystring.stringify({ message: 'foo', username: 'bar'}))
.then(
      function (response) { console.log(response); })
.catch(
      function (error) { console.log(error); })
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format):

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data
>   in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use
>   one of the following options.

…

> In node.js, you can use the querystring module as follows:
>
> ```
> var querystring = require('querystring');
> axios.post('http://something.com/', querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
> ```
>
> You can also use the qs library.